# what is the solution to connect socketio with express with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I want to connect with socket.io to a backend that uses express.

the backend is used as api for other functionalities. So, I use some middleware to add headers to express (you could see that in the code).

the problem is that the socketio on the client side gives the following error:

The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

but I need to keep the '*' to allow all users from any where to access my api.

```
var express = require('express'); var server = express(); 
var app = require('http').Server(server); 
var io = require('socket.io')(app); 
io.set( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" ); 
require('./controllers/watsonIoT.controller').startWatson(io);

server.use(function(request, response, next) { // configuration of headers
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, x-auth");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT")
        next();
    })
    .use('/gui', express.static('views'))
    .use(bodyParser.json())
    .use('/api', mainRouter)
    .get('*', (req, res) => res.redirect('/'))
    .listen(PORT,function(){
        console.log("Starting ... port: "+ PORT);
        // startWatson();
    });
```